# What's the correct method to subclass a singleton class in Objective -C?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have created a singleton class and I want to create a class which is subclass of this singleton class, what is the correct method to do it

Comment: The question needs to clarify if all the code will refer to the singleton by the subclass or if other code will be required to access the subclass singleton via its super-class property.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know about Objective-C in particular, but in general singleton classes should prevent subclassing. If you've got an instance of the base class *and* an instance of the subclass, then you've effectively got two objects you can regard as instances of the base "singleton" class, haven't you?

As soon as you've got two instances, it's not really a singleton any more... and that's leaving aside the possibilities that there are multiple subclasses, or that the subclass itself allows multiple instances to be created.

Of course you can change your base class so it just has a way of getting at a single "default" instance, but that's not quite the same as making it a singleton.

Comment: It becomes a `Doubleton`? haha

Answer (score 13):

If Jon didn't convinced you to not do it, you should do it this way:

In your superclass, init your singleton instance with `[[[self class] alloc] init]` so then you always get an instance of the class with which you are calling the sharedInstance method. And you don't have to overwrite the sharedInstance method in your subclass.

```
 [SuperClass sharedInstance] //-> instance of SuperClass
 [SubClass sharedInstance] //-> instance of Class
```

Comment: I'm coding a cocoa app with two different inspectors (panels). Each panel controller is a singleton, switching the panel contents according to the active document. Much of the panel logic (e.g. register for document activation notifications, etc.) is common to both, so I made a base class for them to inherit. The singleton logic too is common to both so I included it in the base class. Is this design wrong?

Comment: It is wrong. I tried both [[[self class] alloc] init] and [[self alloc] init] and they all returned only singleton of type super class

Comment: as long as the static variable is in the super class, there is only one copy of it to be instantiated. well if you put it in subclasses (in which case you have to migrate the sharedInstance method as well), the singleton concept is not inherited.

Comment: It's not the solution. You need to use a static dictionary to do it.

Comment: How can the static variable be inside the subclass? if the superclass is to be a singleton then the `static` parameter must be present at the super class level @OMGPOP

Answer (score 8):

I made an example "base class" for singleton, you can check it here: https://github.com/stel/DOSingleton

Comment: Dmitry's "base class" does something different (better!) than the other solutions here.  His "base class" allows you to turn any class into a singleton simply by having that class inherit the base class.  This is as opposed to the other solutions here that create a base class that is itself the singleton.  I am using Dmitry's "base class" as a convenience class for creating singletons.  Thank you Dmitry.

Comment: This doesn't prevent a superclass singleton being created after a subclass singleton has been created because the array of instances is keyed on class name.

Answer (score 6):

Jon Skeet makes a good point about whether you’d really have a singleton if you’re allowed to instantiate both the class and its subclass. Putting that aside, here’s a pattern you can use so that so you only have to define the shared-instance getter once, in the parent class:

```
// this code goes in the implementation of the superclass

static Sprocket *defaultSprocket;

+ (instancetype) defaultSprocket
{
    if (defaultSprocket == nil)
        defaultSprocket = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    return defaultSprocket;
}
```

This approach has the following advantages:

- Using `[self class]` allows e.g. `[SprocketSubclass defaultSprocket]` to return an instance of `SprocketSubclass` instead of `Sprocket`
- Using `instancetype` allows the compiler to type-check the result of this method: it’ll be `Sprocket` when you invoke it as `+[Sprocket defaultSprocket]` but `SprocketSubclass` when you invoke it as `+[SprocketSubclass defaultSprocket]`.

Notably, you can define this accessor method in the base class and then you don’t have to do anything in the subclasses!

(Hat tips to NSHipster for [explaining why `instancetype` is so cool](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/) and bbum for [reminding me of it recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437176/371228).)

Comment: when you use - (instancetype), you mean instance method ? Singleton sharedInstance is expected to be class method !

Comment: Why did you use [[self class] alloc] instead of [self alloc]? In class method, self already points to the current class

Comment: That’s true. The difference between `[self class]` and `self` is just stylistic.

Comment: I think that static means existing once. So there must be either 1 superclass or 1 subclass instance !?

Comment: There is a flaw in this solution that if you access [subclass defaultSprocket] then [class defaultSprocket] in that order, on the latter you will be given the subclass singleton instead of the class singleton you wanted. The correct solution is the singleton accessor must be defined in both classes, so that they both have their own static variable holding onto each instance.

Answer (score 4):

If what you are looking for is a quick way to setup new singletons. This pseudo abstract singleton base class is what I use:

### Reusable base class

**H**

```
#define CREATE_SHARED_INSTANCE          \
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {        \
    static dispatch_once_t once;        \
    static id instance = nil;           \
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{             \
        instance = [[self alloc] init]; \
    });                                 \
    return instance;                    \
}

@interface SharedObject : NSObject
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
@end
```

**M**

```
@implementation SharedObject
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    [NSException raise:@"Call to unimplemented sharedInstance" format:@"%@ does not implement sharedInstance.", NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    return nil;
}
@end
```

### Then each subclass

**H**

```
#import "SharedObject.h" 
@interface SomeSubclass : SharedObject
@end
```

**M**

```
@implementation SomeSubclass
CREATE_SHARED_INSTANCE 
@end
```

...and use like any singleton.

```
[[SomesSubclass SharedInstance] someMethod];
```

If you call the abstract base class, or forget to include `CREATE_SHARED_INSTANCE` in your subclass, you will get a friendly exception raised.

This way you can setup a new singletons easily at no performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is implement the standard singleton accessor in both the class and the subclass. This way each class behaves as a proper singleton, that is there is only ever one instance of both. If you attempt to reuse the accessor of the parent class in the subclass and then if you make use of both classes, you run the risk of the accessor returning the wrong instance because their behaviour would depend on the order of how they are accessed.

You should not use instancetype for the singleton accessor to help prevent this mistake. You'll notice Apple don't use it for their singletons e.g. UIApplication and CKContainer.

If you would like existing code that accesses the super-class's singleton method be given an instance of the subclass then likely you need to redesign, see MrJre's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I had multiple targets that needed to have a slightly different singleton implementations: each target would include the base class + a specific subclass. This was achieved by writing the base class like so:

```
+ (SingletonBaseClass*) sharedInstance {
    static SingletonBaseClass * sharedInstance = nil;
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        [sharedInstance customInit];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

The key difference is `[self class]` instead of the actual class name. That way when the we call: `[SingletonSubclass sharedInstance]` the correct object is instantiated.

Please note that this is a specific case, in the general case I agree with previous answers.

Comment: Doesn't this not work, though? Suppose my `SingletonDerivedClass` inherits from `SingletonBaseClass`. Then if I call `[SingletonBaseClass sharedInstance]`, I'll get a singleton instance of `SingletonBaseClass`... and then if I subsequently call `[SingletonDerivedClass sharedInstance]`, I'll get that same singleton instance of `SingletonBaseClass`, rather than a new singleton instance of `SingletonDerivedClass`.

Comment: Well if you use it like that it cannot work. The first call needs to be to the '[SingletonDerivedClass sharedInstance]'. I thought it was clearly stated in my original answer.

Comment: I agree this doesn't work, the class and subclass are sharing the same instance and it can be random which one you get depending on the order they are used.

Comment: This answers exactly to my needs. Note, to avoid the issues mentioned by Zbu, you can create the shared instance adding a conditional "if ([self isMemberOfClass:SingletonBaseClass] == NO]". This way only a subclass can initialize the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the way I solved it is to create a singleton wrapper class which has all the extra functionality. This singleton class *contains* the original singleton (has the singleton instance as a member variable). This way you can avoid dirty tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is how to solve: You need to use a static dictionary to subclass a singleton. For exemple:

Class A : NSObject -> Singleton

Class B : A

Class C : A

```
@implementation A

// Dictionary that holds all instances of API subclasses
static NSMutableDictionary *_sharedInstances = nil;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    id sharedInstance = nil;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
       NSString *instanceClass = NSStringFromClass(self);

       if (_sharedInstances == nil)
           _sharedInstances = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

       // Looking for existing instance
       sharedInstance = [_sharedInstances objectForKey:instanceClass];

       // If there's no instance – create one and add it to the dictionary
       if (sharedInstance == nil) 
       {
          sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
          [_sharedInstances setObject:sharedInstance forKey:instanceClass];
       }
   }
   return sharedInstance;
```

}

Now you can use [B sharedInstance] and [C sharedInstance] without problems!

Comment: Have you tried the performance of this? It seems like you're adding a LOT of lookups.

Comment: I ran a quick benchmark of this method vs the norm.(Adding sharedInstance to every object) Results: This method is ~23X slower. I did 1M cycles of asking for a var, add to self and store back in. 0.000190ms vs 0.004324ms per cycle.

Comment: This method store and query objects in a dictionary. If you think that is slow work with dictionary use another method. I use 3 singletons on my app. For users wait 3x 0.00whatever is nothing. Anyway, the point of the question is create a subclass of singleton. You will not be able to subclass using the default method to create singleton.

Comment: Disagree. Singletons are used very regularly. Slowdowns can get considerable if in a loop and can be problematic if on your main thread.

Comment: Learn to take positive criticism. My comment is addressed directly at the performance hit of this method, which I took the time to build and test, for the benefit of the reader.

Comment: Can you post you 23x faster solution? Because I tried all solutions in this page. Only Dmitry (with DOSingleton) and my solution work for subclassing singletons. Curiously, both of us use a static dictionary to do that. Just post your code, I will test it.

Comment: If you reed my second comment, "this method vs the norm" refers to the regular way to define singletons on a per-class basis. I posted the method I use to simplify setting up singletons yesterday.(why are you deleting your old comments?)

Comment: So your test doesn't make any sense. You CAN NOT subclass a singleton using regular way to define singleton. Basically you are comparing a solution method with a NOT solution method to verify performance, this doesn't make sense. You should compare two algorithms that are both solutions of this questions, to verify which of them is faster. (I didn't delete any comments.)

Comment: If you redefine the implementation of your SharedInstance method on each object, you will in fact get original objects... Even if you implement the base class. At any rate. My original comment was directly on the performance of this method vs regular singleton implementations. This is as much time as im putting into this thread.