# Why is "self = [[Rectangle alloc] init]" in a class method BAD?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class-method

In the document "Objective-C Programming Language" by Apple, page 48 says:

```
+ (Rectangle *)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *) color
{
    self = [[Rectangle alloc] init]; // BAD
    [self setColor:color];
    return self;
}

+ (id)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *)color
{
     id newInstance = [[Rectangle alloc] init]; // GOOD
     [newInstance setColor:color];
     return newInstance;
}


+ (id)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *)color
{
     id newInstance = [[self alloc] init]; // EXCELLENT
     [newInstance setColor:color];
     return newInstance;
}
```

One is bad, one is good, and the other is excellent. Why is that?

Comment: Can you post the URL to that document?  There needs to be a bug filed to capture my answer into the docs.  Happy to file the bug, just can't find the original document.

Comment: @bbum, I also cant find it.

Comment: I don't remember where I found it. So I uploaded it into Dropbox
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/87267422/ObjC_by_Apple.pdf

Answer (score 17):

There is a fourth pattern....

(1) type mismatch is BAD.

(2) static reference to class yields method that won't behave correctly in subclasses

(3) dynamic reference to class means subclasses will be instantiated as subclass instances

---

(4)

```
+ (instancetype)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *)color // Über-bestest evar!
{
     Rectangle *newInstance = [[self alloc] init];
     [newInstance setColor:color];
     return newInstance;
}
```

llvm added the `instancetype` keyword that says "yo! this method returns an instance of whatever class it was called on".   Thus, if you were to subclass the above, you could:

```
RectangleSub *rs = [RectangleSub rectangleOfColor:[NSColor paisleyColor]];
```

But this would warn (beyond the awful color choice):

```
RectangleSub *rs = [Rectangle rectangleOfColor:[NSColor puceColor]];
```

Whereas the (id) return type would not warn in the second case.

Note that I also switched declared `newInstance` to be explicitly of type `Rectangle*`.  This is more better, too, in that *within the context of that method*, `newInstance` can only be safely treated as a `Rectangle*`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  It is new to recent versions of LLVM.  NSHipster has a nice writeup:  http://nshipster.com/instancetype/

Answer (score 9):

```
+ (Rectangle *)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *) color
{
    self = [[Rectangle alloc] init]; // BAD
    [self setColor:color];
    return self;
}
```

In class method `self` refers to the class, not a instance object of it.

---

```
+ (id)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *)color
{
    id newInstance = [[Rectangle alloc] init]; // GOOD
    [newInstance setColor:color];
    return newInstance;
}
```

If Rectangle would be subclassed (MyFancyRectangle), this still would return a plain Rectangle object, while

```
+ (id)rectangleOfColor:(NSColor *)color
{
    id newInstance = [[self alloc] init]; // EXCELLENT
    [newInstance setColor:color];
    return newInstance;
}
```

would return a `MyFancyReactangle` if called like `MyFancyReactangle *r = [MyFancyReactangle rectangleOfColor:[UIColor redColor]]`, as `[self alloc]`is called on the sublass. Note, that here `self` is again called on the class, as `+alloc` is a class method.

For the same reason all `init…` and convenient creator methods should return `id`. It allows subclasses to return subclass'ed objects without the compiler going mad.

Comment: I'd be surprised, if this would compile at all. it is just wrong and should be triggered by the compiler as error.

Comment: The compiler will warn w/a type mismatch related message.

Comment: Which differ between refer to the class object and refer to the instance ?

Comment: sorry @DungProton, I dont get your question.

Comment: @DungProton A class method's `self` is of type `Class`.  In an instance method, `self` is a reference to whatever class the method is defined on (in this case, `Rectangle*`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491906/class-object-vs-instace/15492125?noredirect=1#15492125
I have just asked a question here but seemly they didn't understand my question :(

Comment: @DungProton, what did u expect in that question? this text explains very well what classes, class objects and instances are. Quite difficult to write it even more simple.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, you assign the `self` pointer (which should point to the `Rectangle` class object) to an instance of `Rectangle`. This is absolutely incorrect.

In the second, you hard code a class to instantiate - `Rectangle` in this case.

In the third, you allow the class's identity to determine the class of the instance, rather than specifying it explicitly in code. Then, if your `Dodecahedron` class needs to use this same code, it won't require changing the class name.