# Accessing delegate of super class from subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, delegates

I have four classes **MainVC**, **ParentClient** and **ChildClient1**, **ChildClient2**(which are  subclasses of ParentClient). ParentClient has a delegate to MainVC such that in MainVC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [ParentClient instance].mainViewDelegate = self;
}
```

And then the ParentClient looks like this

```
@interface BaseClient : NSObject

@property (assign) id<MainVCInteraction> mainViewDelegate;
+(instancetype) instance;

@end
```

Now I want to access `mainViewDelegate` from *ChildClient1*, *ChildClient2* and it returns me nil while `[ParentClient instance].mainViewDelegate` returns the correct value

Comment: From the great man himself: "I don't know about Objective-C in particular, but in general singleton classes should prevent subclassing." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394033/whats-the-correct-method-to-subclass-a-singleton-class-in-objective-c

Comment: They are two instances, you should assign their `mainViewDelegate` respectively. `[ParentClient instance].mainViewDelegate = self;` can't affect all the instances of ParentClient and its subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did I removed the BaseClient Class so that ChildClient1, ChildClient2 were no longer subclasses of BaseClient. I defined a objective-c **protocol** file MainVCInteaction.h and made Client1, Client2 look like this:

```
#import "MainVCInteraction.h"
@interface ChildClient1 : NSObject

@property (assign) id<MainVCInteraction> mainViewDelegate;
+(instancetype) instance;

@end


#import "MainVCInteraction.h"
@interface ChildClient2 : NSObject

@property (assign) id<MainVCInteraction> mainViewDelegate;
+(instancetype) instance;

@end
```

And then  MainVC implements this protocol, I assigned the delegate like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [ChildClient1 instance].mainViewDelegate = self;
      [ChildClient2 instance].mainViewDelegate = self;
}
```